# Why implied Conditional Independencies of mediator and confounder are the same?

Tags: r, self-study, bayesian-network, dag, conditional-independence

I am trying to understand why the `impliedConditionalIndependencies` function of the `rethinking` package returns the same value for a mediator and confounder. They both return that D is independent of M, given A. Here is some reproducible code to show the output:

```r
library(rethinking)
library(dagitty)
mediator <- dagitty('dag{M -> A -> D}')
drawdag(mediator)
```

[image]

```r
impliedConditionalIndependencies(mediator)
#> D _||_ M | A

confounder <- dagitty('dag{M <- A -> D}')
drawdag(confounder)
```

[image]

```r
impliedConditionalIndependencies(confounder)
#> D _||_ M | A
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As we can see both return the same output. I can imagine the output of a confounder because when M changes, it doesn't affect the output of D So D is independent of M. But when M changes it affects A and A affects D which means that D may be dependent on M, right? So I was wondering if anyone could explain why the output of mediator and confounder is the same here?

Comment: I'm not sure they are the same outputs...the arrow from A changes direction.

Comment: Hi @GreggH, Yes that is true, but I mean that the output of `impliedConditionalIndependencies` are the same: `D _||_ M | A`

Comment: If you control for A you close the path between D and M (in both DAGs). Therefore, given A, D and M are independent.